# Jquery carousel in WPF

Tags: c#, jquery, wpf, listbox, carousel

I want to create carousel in WPF like [here](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/). (left and right buttons not counted, just bullets)

I've found many solutions how to create carousel in WPF, but it isn't exactly what i need. 
I have listBox of images:

```
<ListBox Name="productImages" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource HorizontalItemsPanel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ImagesCollectionView}}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ProductImageContainerStyle}">
  <ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle Panel="{StaticResource HorizontalItemsPanel}" />
  </ListBox.GroupStyle>
</ListBox>
```

and slider bullets:

```
<ListBox BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#66000000">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBoxItem>
            <Border Background="#4CFFFFFF" Width="6" Height="6" CornerRadius="3"></Border>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Border Background="#FFFFFF" Width="6" Height="6" CornerRadius="3"></Border>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Border Background="#4CFFFFFF" Width="6" Height="6" CornerRadius="3"></Border>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Border Background="#4CFFFFFF" Width="6" Height="6" CornerRadius="3"></Border>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

I don't know how to create "relation" between them - when I click on bullet, image with same index should be shown.

Comment: For example each item can be binded to some Command that will make it current. Are you asking for ready solution?

Comment: @Spawn, some example will be very good. But for now some understandable approach for me is enough.

Comment: Ok, we don't need two listboxes. Create simple Image where you will show Current Image and one ListBox (bullets). SelectedItem in ListBox will be image to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple XAML. What i mean in comment:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=Images}" IsManipulationEnabled="True" ManipulationCompleted="UIElement_OnManipulationCompleted" />
    <ListBox Name="Images" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="20" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <Ellipse Width="15" Height="15" Fill="LightGray"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Image - where we can see our image.
ListBox - our bullets. I don't remove selection borders, but it's just a sample.

Image is binded to SelectedItem.Image property, so our context must be something with this property.

About manipulation. I'm using ListCollectionView as DataContext and OnManipulationCompleted event.

```
private ListCollectionView Context { get; }

private void UIElement_OnManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.TotalManipulation.Translation.X < 5)
    {
        if (Context.CurrentPosition == 0)
            Context.MoveCurrentToLast();
        else
            Context.MoveCurrentToPrevious();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if (e.TotalManipulation.Translation.X > 5)
    {
        if (Context.CurrentPosition == Context.Count)
            Context.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        else
            Context.MoveCurrentToNext();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

As I have tested, it's work perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean from comment :) Thanks

Comment: @demo not at all, it was interesting for me too

Comment: One more question - what should I add, what event to slide this image with touch?

Comment: @demo i didn't work with it, but as i understand, you need to set IsManipulationEnabled="True" and then use ManipulationDelta event..