# Slide images in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, drag

I have collection of images in listBox

```
<ListBox Name="lb" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
  ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}" Width="150" Height="100"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Visible item is only selected one.

How can I slide or scroll images? Or how manage what item should be selected if I drag cursor on visible image to the left or to the right?

Comment: You don't like my solution with Image? :) And if i show how to make it work with touch?

Comment: @Spawn, :D No! But with touch - yes :) I red about ManipulationDelta event and thought there can be easier solution. Currently I need more investigation about that event, cause I have never met it before

Comment: Yesterday I was found a way to test it, so I'll show example. It's easier than you think I suppose.

Comment: I have edited my previos answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34179408/1979354

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar in past project

Here are some bits of the code. More or less it will work as expected, but you may always adjust it as per your needs

This implements behavior of bringing selected item to view by scrolling to desired position and also implement sliding of item/image to left or right.

**Listbox/ItemsControl** *(Binding is not important but useful for dynamic items)*

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behavior:BringSelectionToViewBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPage,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                <ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                               VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

**BringSelectionToViewBehavior.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity;

namespace MyProject.Behaviors
{

    public class BringSelectionToViewBehavior : Behavior<ItemsControl>
    {

        Queue<Point> velocityPoints = new Queue<Point>(4);
        Point PreviousPoint { get; set; }
        DispatcherTimer valocityTimer = new DispatcherTimer();


        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedItem.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(BringSelectionToViewBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedItemChanged));



        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            AssociatedObject.AddHandler(ItemsControl.SizeChangedEvent, (SizeChangedEventHandler)OnWidthChanged);
            AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated += new EventHandler(AssociatedObject_LayoutUpdated);
            AssociatedObject.ReleaseMouseCapture();

            valocityTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20);
            valocityTimer.Tick += valocityTimer_Tick;

        }
        ItemsPresenter itemsPresenter;

        void AssociatedObject_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (itemsPresenter == null)
            {
                itemsPresenter = AssociatedObject.FindChildrenByType<ItemsPresenter>().ToList().First();

                AssociatedObject.MouseMove += AssociatedObject_MouseMove;

                itemsPresenter.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(ItemPresenter_MouseLeftButtonDown), false);
                itemsPresenter.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(ItemPresenter_MouseLeftButtonUp), true);
            }
        }



        public void OnWidthChanged(object s, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<ItemsControl, object>)QueueAnimation, DispatcherPriority.Render, new[] { AssociatedObject, SelectedItem });
        }

        private void QueueAnimation(ItemsControl control, object item)
        {
            BringItemToView(item);
        }

        public static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject s, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.NewValue == null)
                return;

            BringSelectionToViewBehavior behavior = s as BringSelectionToViewBehavior;
            if (!behavior.valocityOverride.HasValue)
                behavior.BringItemToView(e.NewValue);
        }

        private void BringItemToView(object item, EasingMode easeMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut)
        {
            if (item == null || AssociatedObject == null)
                return;

            FrameworkElement element = AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as FrameworkElement;

            BringElementToView(element, easeMode);
        }

        private void BringElementToView(FrameworkElement element, EasingMode easeMode)
        {
            if (element == null)
                return;


            ScrollViewer scrollViewer = element.FindAncestorByType<ScrollViewer>();
            if (scrollViewer != null)
            {
                Point relativePoint = element.TransformToAncestor(scrollViewer).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

                ScrollToPosition(scrollViewer, relativePoint.X, relativePoint.Y, easeMode);
            }
            else
            {
                element.BringIntoView();
            }
        }
        private void ScrollToPosition(ScrollViewer viewer, double x, double y, EasingMode easeMode)
        {

            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
            if (y != 0)
            {
                DoubleAnimation vertAnim = new DoubleAnimation();
                //if (applyEase)
                vertAnim.EasingFunction = new CubicEase() { EasingMode = easeMode };
                vertAnim.From = viewer.VerticalOffset;
                vertAnim.By = y;
                vertAnim.Duration = GetAnimationDuration(y);
                sb.Children.Add(vertAnim);
                Storyboard.SetTarget(vertAnim, viewer);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(vertAnim, new PropertyPath(BringSelectionToViewBehavior.VerticalOffsetProperty));
            }

            if (x != 0)
            {
                DoubleAnimation horzAnim = new DoubleAnimation();

                horzAnim.From = viewer.HorizontalOffset;
                horzAnim.By = x;
                horzAnim.Duration = GetAnimationDuration(x);

                horzAnim.EasingFunction = new CubicEase() { EasingMode = easeMode };

                sb.Children.Add(horzAnim);
                Storyboard.SetTarget(horzAnim, viewer);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(horzAnim, new PropertyPath(BringSelectionToViewBehavior.HorizontalOffsetProperty));
            }
            //overrideDuretion = false;
            sb.Completed += new EventHandler(sb_Completed);
            sb.Begin();

        }

        void sb_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((sender as ClockGroup).Timeline as Storyboard).Remove();

            valocityOverride = null;



        }

        double? valocityOverride;

        private Duration GetAnimationDuration(double distanceToTravel)
        {
            double animTime = Math.Abs(distanceToTravel) * .7;

            if (valocityOverride.HasValue && valocityOverride > 50)
            {
                animTime = Math.Abs(distanceToTravel) * (valocityOverride.Value / 1000);
            }

            if (animTime > 1500)
                animTime = 1500;
            if (animTime < 250)
                animTime = 250;


            return new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(animTime));
        }

        public static double GetVerticalOffset(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (double)obj.GetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty);
        }

        public static void SetVerticalOffset(DependencyObject obj, double value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for VerticalOffset.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalOffsetProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VerticalOffset", typeof(double), typeof(BringSelectionToViewBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnVerticalChanged)));


        public static double GetHorizontalOffset(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (double)obj.GetValue(HorizontalOffsetProperty);
        }

        public static void SetHorizontalOffset(DependencyObject obj, double value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(HorizontalOffsetProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HorizontalOffset.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalOffsetProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HorizontalOffset", typeof(double), typeof(BringSelectionToViewBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnHorizontalChanged)));


        private static void OnVerticalChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollViewer viewer = d as ScrollViewer;
            viewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset((double)e.NewValue);
        }

        private static void OnHorizontalChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollViewer viewer = d as ScrollViewer;
            viewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((double)e.NewValue);
        }

        void valocityTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Point currentPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);
            velocityPoints.Enqueue(currentPoint);
            if (velocityPoints.Count > 4)
                velocityPoints.Dequeue();
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (itemsPresenter.IsMouseCaptured)
            {

                Point CurrentPoint = e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);

                Vector offset = PreviousPoint - CurrentPoint;

                PreviousPoint = CurrentPoint;

                if (offset.X != 0)
                {
                    Viewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(Viewer.HorizontalOffset + offset.X);
                }

            }
        }


        public ScrollViewer Viewer { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the MouseLeftButtonDown event of the ItemPresenter control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void ItemPresenter_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //Viewer.ApplyAnimationClock(BringSelectionToViewBehavior.HorizontalOffsetProperty, null);
            Border bd = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).FindAncestorByType<Border>();


            if (bd == null || (bd != null && bd.Name != "GripBarElement"))
            {
                Viewer = AssociatedObject.FindChildrenByType<ScrollViewer>().ToList().First();

                PreviousPoint = e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);
                itemsPresenter.CaptureMouse();
                velocityPoints.Clear();
                valocityTimer.Start();
            }

        }

        private double CalculateMouseSpeed()
        {
            if (velocityPoints.Count > 1)
            {
                Point first = velocityPoints.Dequeue();
                return velocityPoints.Aggregate<Point, Point, double>(first, (s, pt) => new Point(s.X, pt.X), pt => pt.X - pt.Y);
            }
            return 0;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the MouseLeftButtonUp event of the ItemPresenter control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void ItemPresenter_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (itemsPresenter.IsMouseCaptured)
            {
                if (Viewer == null)
                    return;


                valocityTimer.Stop();
                itemsPresenter.ReleaseMouseCapture();

                double MouseSpeed = CalculateMouseSpeed() / 3;
                double newtotal = 5 * MouseSpeed;
                double newOffset = Viewer.HorizontalOffset + newtotal;
                double maxOffset = itemsPresenter.ActualWidth - (itemsPresenter.ActualWidth / AssociatedObject.Items.Count);
                if (newOffset < 0)
                {
                    newtotal += 0 - newOffset;
                }
                else if (newOffset > maxOffset)
                {
                    newtotal -= newOffset - maxOffset;
                }
                newOffset = Viewer.HorizontalOffset + newtotal;

                int newIndex = (int)System.Math.Round(newOffset / (itemsPresenter.ActualWidth / AssociatedObject.Items.Count));
                object objToSet = AssociatedObject.ItemsSource.OfType<object>().ElementAt(newIndex);

                if (objToSet != null)
                {
                    valocityOverride = MouseSpeed;
                    if (!object.Equals(SelectedItem, objToSet))
                        SelectedItem = objToSet;
                    BringItemToView(objToSet, EasingMode.EaseOut);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Give it a try and see if this can solve your issue.